# LinkedIn and Open Graph : site not shareable on LinkedIn without reason

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to make my website shareable on LinkedIn.

URL : https://www.jedecouvremercator.com/

My website is W3C validate. I have followed all the LinkedIn recommendations and Google recommendations. My Open Graph meta is correct and the website is shareable on all other platforms.

But when I'm trying to share it on LinkedIn or when I use a custom link to share it, LinkedIn can't display the meta information.

(I always use garbage into the URL to kill cache before verifying my changes).

Can somebody tell me why?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The site in your URL is down, and you didn't post any code, so that makes this difficult, but not impossible.  I can still view your URL through [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190618064744/https://www.jedecouvremercator.com/), and when I try to share the archive.org URL, like this...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20190618064744%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.jedecouvremercator.com%2F
```

When I click the above, everything works perfectly fine for me.  Example:

[image]

If you need more info: [Official LinkedIn Documentation for Formatting URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin) and [Official LinkedIn Documentation for OpenGraph Tags and Prefilled Sharing](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).